# Finding GCD by decomposition into prime factors

Tags: java, greatest-common-divisor

I have to write a program that calculate GCD by finding mutual 
 prime factors in two numbers.
The program will print two list of prime factors of two given number and in the last line will write a list with the mutual numbers.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
      ArrayList <Integer> LIST1=new ArrayList<Integer>();
      ArrayList <Integer> LIST2=new ArrayList <Integer>();
      ArrayList <Integer> LIST3=new ArrayList <Integer>();
      int a=in.nextInt();
      int b=in.nextInt();
      int i;
      for(i=2;i<=a;i++){
         while(a%i==0){           LIST1.add(i);  
            a=a/i;}
      }
      int j;
      for(j=2;j<=b;j++){
         while(b%j==0){
            LIST2.add(j);
            b=b/j;
         }
      }
     int p = LIST1.size();
     int q = LIST2.size();
     int MIN=Math.min(p,q);
      int k;
      for(k=0;k<=MIN-1;k++){
         int m;
         for(m=0;m<=MIN-1;m++){
            if(LIST1.get(k)==LIST2.get(m)){
                 int c=LIST1.get(k);
                 LIST3.add(c); 
            } 
         } 
      }
      System.out.println(LIST1);
      System.out.println(LIST2);
      System.out.println(LIST3);
    }
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: http://www.sololearn.com/app/java/playground/cQXspVLQXczD/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Before you ask a question, there is an expectation that you show some effort to solve a specific problem. Stack Overflow is not a free code writing or resource discovery service.

Comment: http://www.sololearn.com/app/java/playground/cQXspVLQXczD/

Answer (score 0):

Finding the prime factors of `a` and `b` seems ok to me.

But the logic in finding the common factors is probably wrong. Try it with e.g. 24 and 40, and single-step through the `LIST3` collection part. How often do you collect the factor 2 into the result? As the GCD is 8, you should count the factor 2 exactly three times. It can be tricky to find the common subset of two lists where elements can occur more than once.

It might be easier to collect the prime factors not into a `List`, but into a `Map` with the prime factor as key and the count as value. If you haven't used a `Map` before, it's absolutely worth learning about that data structure.

P.S. when you've got the program running correctly, I'd recommend to post it at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ where we can give you some useful hints on coding style that don't fit to Stackoverflow.